# EF 6 get entity after adding

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF 6 in my .NET MVC app. I have these classes:

```
public class Member 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int FactoryID { get; set; }
    public Factory Factory { get; set; }
}

public class Factory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

code to add:

```
var newMember = new Member();
newMember.Name = 1;
newMember.FactoryID = 2;
context.Members.Add(newMember);
context.SaveChanges();
```

code to get:

```
var member = context.Members.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
var factory = member.Factory;
```

so, when I add `Member` in one API call, then get `Member` in another API call then `Member.Factory` is defined.

When I try to get `Member` right away after adding then `Member.Factory` is `NULL`.

What's the reason of it? And how can it be resolved?

Comment: did you include Factory in your IQueryable? More or less like so: myCtx.Members.Include(m=>m.Factory)

Comment: no, I didn't add `Include()`, I can't understand why it works in one case but doesn't work in another. If I add `.Include()` it works fine. But I would like to figure out the reason.

Comment: are you using transaction ??

Comment: Do you have lazy loading enabled? The proxies to enable that might not be set on Add. You could also try `newMember = context.Members.Add(newMember);` to see if it makes any difference

Comment: If the Member's Factory is already present in your DbContext's Change Tracker it will be attached to the Member when it's loaded.

Comment: @federico scamuzzi no, I don't use Transaction

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft it's already in DB very long.

Comment: @ESG I don't have lazy loading enabled `base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

Comment: The Change Tracker is the DbContext's in-memory collection of Entity objects that have been loaded already, and when it loads an Entity it will "fix-up" relationships between the newly-loaded Entitity and Entities already loaded in memory.  This might explain the behavior you describe.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft So I need to reset Change Tracker somehow?

Comment: Yes.  Each request should start with a new DbContext instance, which will have an empty Change Tracker.

Comment: how can I reset it?

Comment: Use a new DbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it would work sometimes but not others is because EF will provide related entities it knows about when you reference entities by ID. If Lazy loading is enabled, EF will go to the DB to pull back any related entities that it doesn't know about. When it comes to serializing responses though, Lazy loading can result in performance issues or cyclic reference errors.

For example, with lazy loading turned off:

If I do something like:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
   var member = new Member
   {
      FactoryId = 3;
      // ... 
   }
   context.Members.Add(member);
   context.SaveChanges();
   return member;
}
```

the returned Member's "Factory" reference will be #null because that EF context had no notion of what Factory ID 3 actually was. The insert will succeed provided that a data record for Factory ID #3 exists, but the context does not know about it.

If in another example I do something like this:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{ 
   // Call some code using this context that results in the following running...
   var factory = context.Factories.Single(x => x.FactoryId == 3);
   // more code...

   var member = new Member
   {
      FactoryId = 3;
      // ... 
   }
   context.Members.Add(member);
   context.SaveChanges();
   return member;
}
```

In this case, EF will return Factory #3 along with the member because the context instance knew about Factory #3. When member was saved, the known reference was automatically associated.

The above example uses a DbContext in a using block, which makes the scenario seem obvious, however, with code that uses an IoC container to scope a DbContext to a request for example it can be a little less clear cut for any given scenario across various methods etc. that may be called to work out what entities the DbContext may, or may not know about.

When dealing with references where you will want to return details about entities and their references, or following code would benefit from accessing references, my typical advice is to set references, not FKs in your entities. This way you assure that the entity you are creating is in a complete and fit for purpose state.

For instance:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{ 
   var factory = context.Factories.Single(x => x.FactoryId == factoryId); 
   var member = new Member
   {
      Factory = factory;
      // ... 
   }
   context.Members.Add(member);
   context.SaveChanges();
   return member;
}
```

I avoid exposing FKs entirely within my entities to enforce using the references, and use Shadow Properties (EFCore) and mapping (EF6) to ensure FKs are not accessible in my entities.  The trouble with FKs is that when editing entities that have both a reference and a FK column, there are 2 sources of truth. Does updating the Factory change the factory reference, or does updating the FactoryId? What if I have a Factory reference pointing at Factory ID 3, but I change FactoryId on Member to 4?  Some code may depend on the FK, while other may go to the Factory reference.

Explicitly working with references means that related entities are asserted at that point (rather than waiting for any number of FK violations on SaveChanges). It will use any loaded references the context has already loaded, or go to the DB if needed.

Where I do use FKs over references is for bulk operations where I just want to update or insert a large amount of information as quickly as possible. In these cases I use a bounded context with bare bones simple entity definitions with FKs and no references to create, set FKs, and save. No need for returning complete data and references.